# Git status shows 2 files that I deleted

Tags: git, git-status

How do I get rid of these two files?

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    public_html/images/summits/StrongerThanYouThink.jpg
    deleted:    public_html/images/summits/StrongerThanYouThinkc6.jpg
```

Comment: They'll be gone from the working directory and the index as soon as you `commit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files are listed in the section "*Changes to be committed*". After you run `git commit`, those files will be deleted from the HEAD of your repository and `git status` will no longer show them as staged.